# How to get div target value in AngularJs on div click?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code, I did not get an alert.

**Html**

```
<div ng-click="Myfunc(event)">test</div>
```

**Script**

```
$scope.Myfunc = function(event) {
    alert(event.target.html());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Formatting, wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use angular.element functions like .html(), it should be an angular element, but not raw DOM element.

```
  $scope.Myfunc = function(event)
     {
      alert(angular.element(event.target).html());
     }
```

`$event` must be passed

```
 <div ng-click="Myfunc($event)">test</div>
```